# Firebase Messages to iOS without APNs?

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to send data messages to iOS devices in FCM **without** using APNs?

I need to send some "live" data to my iOS client app while it is running, instead of polling my servers.

There are 2 reasons I want FCM **not** to use Apple notifications:

- I don't want any kind of system notification/badge/alert to be shown to the user when the app is not running. This is pure app data transfer while the app is running, the rest of the messages can be ignored.
- When using Apple notifications the user will be asked the first time if (s)he wants to grant my app notification permissions. If denied my whole app will stop working since the data will not be updated.

I found this post at Firebase Google Groups [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/EC9Yv1X0is0/2V__CmVrAAAJ) where some of the Firebase guys hints that if I don't use iOS specific keys like `sound`, `body`, `badge`, `content_available` or others:

```
{
    "to" : "<device_id>",
    "data" : {
        "customKey1" : "value1",
        "customKey2" : "value2",
        "customKey3" : "value3",
    }
}
```

then they will not use APNs.

All I need is a guarantee of a delivery while my app is in foreground, I wonder if there is a way to configure FCM or messages themselves to reach that goal.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use Firebase's Realtime Database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Comment: Yes, that will definitely solve the problem. Unfortunately migrating the backend will take some time, which I don't have now... FCM was going to help me with just a small subset of my functionality which is "live". Trying to understand if it is suitable for such tasks or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a follow up on this. I'm finding that with React Native using this library https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/receiving-messages i am able to receive data only messages to the iOS simulator (which doesnt support APNS) so looks like data only bypasses APNS.